# How can I combine 2 PDA's into 1

Tags: automata, context-free, pushdown-automata

I need to form PDA for this language: {$a^nb^m|n=m \vee n=2m$}

I know the idea of building each one separately but how do I combine them into 1 PDA?

LHS: for every 'a' I push 'A' inside stack and for every 'b' I eject 'A'.

RHS:for every 'a' I push 'A' inside stack and for every 'b' I eject 2 times 'A'.

How can I combine them? Can I somehow use non determinism?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Construct one PDA for $n=m$ and another one for $n=2m$. Branch to one of them using an $\epsilon$ transition at the very beginning.